# How can I get the correct response for the below code of adding an event listener?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
for(var i = 0 ; i < document.querySelectorAll(".btn").length; i++){
  var btn = document.querySelectorAll(".btn")[i];
  var btnName = btn.innerHTML;
  btn.addEventListener("click",function(){
   console.log(btnName);
  });
}
```

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.btn{
  border-style: none;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 0 20px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>replit</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
<button class="btn">w</button>
  <button class="btn">a</button>
   <button class="btn">s</button>
    <button class="btn">d</button>
     <button class="btn">k</button>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In the above code, I want to print the inner HTML of the button in the console, when clicked, but instead of getting a specific result for specific buttons, I am getting the same value for every button which is the last button inner HTML.

for Example:
problem:
when I click the w button "k" gets printed in console instead of "w".
when I click the a button "a" gets printed in console instead of "a".
when I click the k button "k" gets printed.

desired result:
when I click the w button "w" gets printed in console.
when I click the a button "a" gets printed in console.
when I click the k button "k" gets printed in console.

How can I print the specific inner HTML of a specific button?

Comment: You should not. Do it like `document.querySelectorAll(".btn").forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', e => console.log(e.target.innerHTML)));`.

Comment: Why do you call `document.querySelectorAll(".btn")` for `(document.querySelectorAll(".btn").length * 2` times? Do it once, store the result and ust that result.

Answer (score 3):

You should cache the elements

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");
for(let i = 0 ; i < buttons.length; i++){
   button[i].addEventListener("click",function(){
     console.log(this.textContent);
  });
}
```

or use forEach

```
function myClick(){
  console.log(this.textContent);
});
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  document.querySelectorAll(".btn")
   .forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener("click",myClick));
})
```

But instead PLEASE delegate from the nearest static container

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    const tgt = e.target.closest("button.btn");
    if (tgt) console.log(tgt.textContent);
  });
});
```

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    const tgt = e.target.closest("button.btn");
    if (tgt) console.log(tgt.textContent);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.btn {
  border-style: none;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 0 20px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <button class="btn">w</button>
  <button class="btn">a</button>
  <button class="btn">s</button>
  <button class="btn">d</button>
  <button class="btn">k</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, i am new to JS and I really didn't get any of this, but the const data type helped me. Thanks.